# azure mysql cleardb installation

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

thinking of the AWS implementation of RDSs is there an equivalent implementation on Azure ?
Can clearDB provisioned and connect through a compute node ? For clearDB to be provisioned do we need another computer instance running ?

Answer (score 1):

Azure SQL Database is the only first-party relational database service hosted on Azure.  ClearDB provides a third-party MySQL relational database service on Azure. ClearDB is an instance-level service that relies on Azure VMs to host a MySQL server. For more details on ClearDB, please see their [[FAQ]](https://www.cleardb.com/developers/help/faq)